# What questions should go here vs. ask different?

Tags: discussion

Since Mac OS is a unix-based OS, I'm wondering what kind of questions should be asked in askdifferent vs. the UNIX StackExchange? Is it as simple as "if you are asking about something while using Mac OS, then you should use askdifferent"? Or would you say that askdifferent is reserved for less code-heavy questions.

The borderline case I have in mind is a question about how to do something using the command line (terminal). This is a technical question and the answer will most likely be the same in UNIX.

It is my sense that the folks frequenting the UNIX stack are more tech-savvy (and there are more of them), so the chances of getting a command-line question answered in a satisfactory way is higher there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your main description is quite accurate: my impression is that the community here is more knowledgeable about the command line than the community at Ask Different. Which doesn't mean that the folks at Ask Different don't know their stuff, many of them do! Only that there are more users here with command line knowledge than there are there. So if I had a question about the shell and I was using macOS, I would probably ask here. That said, such questions are also on topic there so it really is up to you and where you might feel more comfortable.

Now, there is a question of scope. While Ask Different and Unix & Linux have significant overlap there are also many things that wouldn't be on topic here at all. If you check our ["on topic" page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), you will find:

> Unix and Linux Stack Exchange is for users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems.
>
> If your question is about:
>
> [. . . ]
>
> - The Unix foundation underlying MacOS (but generally not
>   frontend application questions)
>
> [. . . ]

In other words, questions about the GUI of MacOS are not on topic here and should instead be asked on Ask Different. However, questions that are about the Unix underbelly of the system are perfectly welcome here. Just be aware that if the issue is something that is mac-specific, we might not be aware of it although there are quite a few regulars here who are macOS users.